# Need Help : Angular Router and Navigation Project not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-router

I trying to create project with Angular Routes Tutorial from below site.

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8104/angular-router-tutorial

While i running project getting below error message in VS code terminal window.

[image: ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null]

After loading localhost window as getting error message " Cannot GET / " in loading page.

[image: Cannot GET message as displaying in loading page]

i didn't use loadChildren concepts in my project. but i got error. I updated screenshots for app.module.ts and routerConfig.ts file implemented code changes.

[image: app.module.ts file]

[image: routerConfig.ts file]

Kindly clear me. What i missed? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you done a search inside of your repo for `loadChildren`? At first glance it doesn't look like it should be throwing that error.

Comment: Did you get any error while routing to localhost*/home ?

Comment: First check where you are calling the loadChildren method, the webserver log should not be throwing any error when starting up.

Comment: Try rebuild the project. If that won't work, try create a new project. I had some issues  in the past with the build process. If you followed that tutorial strictly, you should not receive that error. Also, which angular version are you using?

Comment: @alphapilgrim  i searched in my whole project , i didn't use "loadChildren" anywhere. Suspecting this error from angular version problems. not sure.

Comment: @Krish, While routing to "http://localhost:*/home" getting message as " Cannot GET /home"! In console showing as 404 error.

Comment: @BrunoFarias , I didn't use this loadChildren method anywhere. i can't confirm why i can't able to run the project. without using this method i got error message in VS code Terminal window as "ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null".

Comment: @DavidFontes, I did rebuild the project . not working so that tried with new project with same implementation. but getting same error. That ariticle project implemented with Angular 4 . But i tried with Angular 8.3.4 version. May be that is the reason for this issue. still i can't confirm why i am getting this issue. if we download source code from that site, then we can do run the project , it will be work as verified in my local machine.

Comment: Try to post your code to stackblitz so we can replicate/debug the issue..

Comment: Finally, this project working fine in "stackblitz" site. I don't know how its working. Same project base not working in my local machine. Nothing i changed in project base code. its same as from my local machine code. URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbze3r